# Create buttons dynamically and show few details based on the id

Tags: android, dynamic, android-button

I am developing a new Android app, i have listed out the records. Now need to show the particular record while clicking on the corresponding button.

Can somebody help me to share how to create buttons dynamically and assign record id into it?

Comment: Please show your existing codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button btn=new Button(this);
btn.setId(you record id here);
```

then add this button to your view

Comment: If i add it in view., how can i make it dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
 Button button2 = new Button(this);
     button2.setId(recordId);
 relativeLayout.addView(button2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do as below
r
 LinearLayout btnLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

```
Button send = new Button(this);

    send.setText("Send");
    send.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
 btnLayout.addView(send);   
  send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  //Write yout code here
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you list it out in a ListView?? If you can do so, you can dynamically add items easily, and get the click function from listItem's onclick listner

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // Write your click action here

            }
        });
```